# Flickering screen when scrolling in Gvim

Tags: vim

So in vim all kinds of scrolling works perfectly, but in Gvim when scrolling screen flickers, especially noticable on faster scrolls like `pgdn/pgup`, `Ctrl+U` and `Ctrl+D`. Same thing when I scroll by dragging slider with mouse. I tried different background colors, but it does not make any difference.

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using plugins that handle `<C-D>` or `<C-U>`? Try to check with `:map <C-U>` or `:map <C-D>`.

Comment: I don't. I rebind PGUP and PGDN to act as C-D and C-U, but I can comment those line, it's still same problem. This flickers happens no matter what kind of scrolling I use, even when I drag side scroll with mouse.

Comment: Could you try `:set nowrap`?

Comment: Tried, makes no difference.

Comment: How about `:set lazyredraw`?

Comment: No change whatsoever.

Comment: Same here, Anybody found a solution yet?

Comment: try `gvim -u NONE -U NONE`

Comment: I've reported this problem at [vim's issue tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/701).

Answer (score 1):

Ask the developer(s) to make sure that a screen redraw is double-buffered.

I remember running into this years ago when I was using plain, non-antialiased X11 draw calls in Gvim (around version 6.0).  In **that** case, the drawing speed was not-noticeable.  When using anything anti-aliased, I could observe the flicker.

Obviously, the double-buffering is **not** necessary for the original terminal code and I'm assuming that the GUI updates are derived from the original terminal update code.

NOTE: This answer is only here for a reference for future development.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar problem in Gvim on windows. During scrolling bottom and top line flickers, it's even worse with e.g. 10j.

I have been able to eliminate it completely by adding lines in my .vimrc:

```
set lazyredraw
nnoremap <silent> j j:redraw<CR>
nnoremap <silent> k k:redraw<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is to use [Vim-Qt](https://github.com/equalsraf/vim-qt), which is a fork of Vim with the GUI being based on Qt instead of GTK. Although it does have some shortcomings like lack of scrollbars, lack of maintenance (last commit 2 years ago), its advantage is that it doesn't flicker at all.

[My fork of Vim-Qt](https://github.com/10110111/vim-qt) now implements the scrollbars, so if you need them, you may want to try it instead of original Vim-Qt.